# "Add a comment" doesn't appear below a question but appears below an answer when not logged in

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web

I was trying to check into the situation described in the recent question -

[Trying to comment on a particular question on the full site crashes Android Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369434/824803)

I was not logged in. I was checking it in Chrome as in the linked question.

*Add a comment* does not appear below a question when not logged in.

> [image: question]

Though it appears below an answer.

> [image: answer]

Is this intentional?

Comment: Relatedly, this bug doesn't appear to happen in the responsive site.