# Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

[Today we changed the way we sort answers on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/564240). We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

The history of feature requests to unpin the accepted answer on Stack Overflow [dates back to 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) and has been raised almost every year since. This year within the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-projec) we [did research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411192/outdated-answers-unpinning-the-accepted-answer-a-b-test) that [showed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/564240) that we are good to proceed with the accepted answer unpinned.

#### Would you like to have the accepted answer unpinned on your site?

We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. (Please let me acknowledge in advance that we will not be able to run a test on each site.)

Currently we are planning to move forward with one of two scenarios, based on your feedback:

1. Unpin the accepted answer on all SE sites by default and pin it back on a few sites that ask us to do so.
2. Keep the accepted answer pinned on all SE sites by default and unpin it on a few sites that ask us to do so.

Please let us know what you think will work best for your site! If you can discuss this question with your community it would be awesome. We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.

Site settings are per-site and child metas are also considered a "site".

---

**Update**

As [Anita Taylor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/349251/anita-taylor) shared:

> The [Public Platform team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together) will go through these requests and determine what to prioritize, defer and decline. We ask for your patience -- key members of the team are on vacation over the next few weeks, so we won't be able to triage these requests until mid-to-late October.

---

**Update 2**

Thanks to everyone for the feedback. Seeing that some sites do not want to unpin the accepted answer, we decided to move forward with the status quo and not to change the default behaviour on existing sites. If you think unpinning the accepted answer on your site makes sense, please do the following:

1. Start a meta discussion on your per-site meta.
2. When the discussion is completed and the community agrees to change the default behaviour (agrees to unpin the accepted answer), please ask one of the site moderators to add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the question. It will generate a ticket and let CMs know that we need to adjust the site setting for your site.
3. We would appreciate it if you add the outcome of the discussion to the [accepted answer in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/274323). This will allow all of us to see the full picture.

There's no need to do this on the sites that are currently on the list; we have already adjusted the site setting for them.

Comment: My upvote on this post reflects that I think it's great to solicit per-site feedback instead of copying SO changes to the network, not that I necessarily support the change made on SO.

Comment: This is just brilliant! Not only because I very much want to not have the accepted answer first (they're too often not the best answer), but also because of the way you are approaching this, asking for feedback before pushing network-wide. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would be a mistake to make this different per site. I would much rather unpin it every where and have a link near the answer sort selection  to navigate directly to the accepted answer. If there is an accepted answer, there's a nice visible green button or something to get there. That makes it easier to document accepted answers  as well.

Comment: What is the process to request this for a specific site? I'll have to check with the other mods, but this is something we specifically requested on Skeptics years ago as the concept of accepting an answer doesn't really make sense for us, and the pinning is harmful.

Comment: @ColleenV: Speaking personally, not as a CM (I'm certainly not speaking on behalf of what the company will do): I like the idea of unpinning the accepted answer, but leaving some easy way to navigate from the question to the accepted answer (e.g. something like "This user has accepted an answer. `[Click here to jump to the accepted answer.](link)`."

Comment: @MadScientist: Given that it hasn't yet been decided how this will be rolled out network-wide, I think that right now, the idea is to help decide whether the accepted answer should be unpinned or remain pinned on the rest of the network besides SO - and then, once that's settled, a process will be established for having the relevant setting be enabled or disabled on specific sites.

Comment: @V2Blast I think it's a good compromise so that search engine drive-bys pick up the highest voted answer, acceptance still gives an answer extra visibility and users who understand what answer acceptance means can still easily see the AA.

Comment: It looks like [Google lists the accepted answer first instead of highest scored](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com+When+to+use+%22If+I+was%22+vs.+%22If+I+were%22%3F&hl=en&ei=7AE5YYiZEa6p5NoPheqIuAI&oq=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com+When+to+use+%22If+I+was%22+vs.+%22If+I+were%22%3F&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6BQgAEM0COgQIHhAKUK2JAVialgJglJoCaAFwA3gAgAGUAYgB2BiSAQUxOS4xM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp) Is that something SE controls? (For that particular question, that's the desirable outcome, but it may not always be)

Comment: Doesn't  this mean the button that sorts answers according to number of "Votes" becomes obsolete? Maybe changing the button "active" to "newest" would make more sense.

Comment: A better idea: go to each meta site and make a post there as to whether they should be pinned or not there.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No? Votes still sorts by highest votes. Active is most recently active, meaning it's been added or edited recently, Oldest is sorted by date of post, oldest first. Neither of the other views is by score, only Votes. Making Active into Newest would just be a reversal of the Oldest sort, which, while potentially useful, is not the same as Active sort.

Comment: @Catija  Wouldn't unpinning the accepted answer mean that listing answers according to their scores become the default on SO?  That is what I understood by `By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score)`

Comment: We still need a sort button for it, though, @Mari-LouA - we remember users' choices when they change the sort, so if you change to Active, you will see Active as your default until you switch to something else. So having the "Votes" button visible allows people to see which sort they have active and switch to it if it's inactive. That default only applies to people who haven't manually overridden their preferred sort.

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't roll this out to all sites before we have time to discuss it among ourselves :) A week at least!

Comment: @bobble: Judging from the post, a decision on the network-wide default for this won't be made until September 19th, so you've got at least a week :)

Comment: Has this proposal been communicated to the moderators across the network?

Comment: Can you clarify whether this change will affect local child metas as well, and whether the setting can be different on the main site and its meta (i.e. pin on meta but not on main or vice versa)?

Comment: Enroll it as one week test on all sites, and then back to usual, and enable as per request. For se I'm active on, I would like to see that by default, just few days ago was thinking about it - and viola this feature is already here - amazing. And be prepared to disable for those who do not like it, get a list to whom it is not enabled by default.

Comment: As a regular user, I not sure I understand, completely, the why of this. I get that there may be highly voted "correct" answers where there is a low-voted accepted (perhaps "incorrect" answer). I truly do get that, and have seen it. However, what this is saying is that the user's problem is no longer the 'reason' to solve. What do I mean? give two answers, A gets +50 votes, while B gets +30 votes and accepted. The OP chose B as the most helpful, and yet, we _no longer care_ about the usefulness to the asker (?)

Comment: @CGCampbell I think the usefulness for the asker is not relevant anymore after the accept, (his/her/or else) problem is solved, what we need to focus then is the usefulness for new visitors (so, it's best to have a "colectively approved" solution at the top, sorted via vote instead).

Comment: @CGCampell " we no longer care about the usefulness to the asker (?)" I think that nails it. Indeed we don't. The asker can of course kind of say that no existing answer was helpful to him, but what does it matter to anyone else? It may be a hint that people misunderstood the question or that it's still unsolved but it also may just mean that the asker moved on. In the end, the signal is not reliable. So better not put much weight on it regarding the sorting order

Comment: @ACuriousMind Site settings are per-site and, yes, child metas are considered a "site". :)

Comment: "Please let us know what you think will work best for your site!" What's a good way to let you know, without undermining the site's autonomy by opening up the discussion to a larger audience?

Comment: I wonder if the simple "accepted post is pinned second, if it's not the top-scoring answer" works (?).

Comment: Across all of the SE I've ever perused in 7.5y, there's only one question I'd do this to : [Gender-neutral alternative to "craftsmanship"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship). Not because the question irks me (which it does) but because the accepted answer has +64, and *the correct answer* has +274. There should be a threshold using a ratio, not a simple count, at which this engages. A simple majority does not equal *the gods have spoken*, but a sample size of over 300 at a ratio of 1:4 should tell you something.

Comment: You can add whatever you want, just don't change anything. As in, go into your profile, tick the new box, and now it'll do that. Don't make me have to run scripts. And don't make me have to go into my profile and un-tick some new box, like I had to do last time, but hey, at least there was a tick box.... "We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings" - how about *I* can change it *if I want to*. Because on DiY all this will likely do is bring what few joke answers we have to the top. You guys aren't Apple are you? There's no reason to force any change ever.

Comment: @Mazura the [accepted answer on this question is far worse.... 36 downvotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70685/why-is-taking-a-biscuit-a-bad-thing-in-the-uk). But it doesn't matter because surely visitors and users alike can scroll past the accepted answer and see there are answers which are better supported

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm guessing that an 'accept' keeps it from being auto deleted from flagging? Can they not delete it themselves because it's accepted? That's several layers of fail beyond the scope of this question.... At least it's greyed out, so it's likely to get scrolled passed. Honestly, at this point I use *my* upvotes as bookmarks to the 'correct' answer. Here, that was [the script to ignore this whole thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/255297).

Comment: @Mazura  I'm no good with scripts. I tried once or twice to install them but they don't work for me or it was the something-monkey program that didn't work. So, I gave up. I get by fine. Accepted answers cannot be deleted. I think there are (or there should be) exceptions if the accepted answer is particularly biased, offensive, racist or incendiary.

Comment: Meta_SO has conducted the "Outdated Answers project"...when will Meta_SO be conducting the "Outdated Downvotes project"? Seems without the Accepted Answer being pinned to the top, Downvotes (and in particular irrelevant/outdated ones) are given increased weight.

Comment: Is it worth revisiting the decision to not allow us to delete accepted answers now?  I have an answer that at the time was "there is no feature that supports what you are doing.", but there is now such a feature.  It was accepted at the time, but there is no way for me to delete it now and the asker is unresponsive to moving the answer flag.  Seems like the original limitation to prevent the accepted answer from being deleted might no longer be useful.

Comment: @Matt Sounds like you should just update your answer with the feature that now exists.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, but someone else has already posted an answer that covers it in the mean time.  I could just link to their answer, but seems cleaner to just remove my answer.  It might be possible to just start acquiring downvotes too since it actually not accurate.  It seems weird that I'm just held hostage and have to take the potential downvotes.  To get rid of the question now, I have to jump through some hoops to get it unassociated from my username, but I don't think that actually gets the answer removed.

Comment: @Matt Two correct answers can happily co-exist. The system is designed that way.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, our community (Seasoned Advice) is somewhat "slow" in Meta participation, and we don't have had much activity on that question. Also, I overlooked your deadline when communicating to them how to decide. Can you consider extending the deadline/gathering the results later? You can get it from here, https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/.

Comment: @rumtscho Thank you for the question on Meta Seasoned Advice. Yes, we still are waiting for the decision you are going to make. Mover over, regardless of what is the default value, we are going to adjust this site setting for each community that expresses the need. Whenever you have the decision, please add it to the table in the accepted answer of this question :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky please include Coffee, Parenting and Gardening in the list, and for the latter, we really should wait until after the election.

Comment: YYYYEEEEESSSSSSS, about time!

Comment: I like the simplicity of @RebeccaJ.Stones idea. [Pin the accepted answer second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369577#comment1234565_369568) if it's not the top-scored. Please Rebecca, post your simple but effective solution as an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [Okay done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370156/351283).

Comment: Nicolas, so now the ***new metric*** is: Where does an accepted answer place, compared to others. --- True [comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers#comment1234245_369568) previously: (Tour Page):  "The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". - Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.". --- Now it's an ***indicator*** of whether the OP's idea of *correctness* aligns with the community - an announcement of where they fit in. Unwelcoming.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the default going forward is still _pin the accepted answer_, but any community can decide to change that with a discussion on meta & proper consensus; is that correct?

Comment: @zcoop98 yes, it is correct.

Comment: Will keeping the pin also be the setting for new sites established through Area 51 in the future?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Full List of Community Discussions

✅ indicates that this has been implemented on the specific site.

| Site | Verdict | Site Discussion Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Academia | 50/50 | [Should the answer that appears on "top" be the OP's "accepted answer" or the answer with most votes?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/) |
| Anime |  | [Does the community want the accepted answers to be pinned to the top?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4444) |
| Apple |  | [Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/p) |
| Arqade | ✅ Keep Pin | https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16087/163757 |
| Ask Ubuntu | ✅ Unpin | [Should we unpin the accepted answer from the top of the list?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19728) |
| Ask Ubuntu (Meta) | ✅ Keep Pin | [Should we unpin the accepted answer from the top of the list on meta?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19733) |
| Astronomy | ✅ Unpin | https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/803 |
| Aviation | ✅ Unpin | https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253 |
| Bicycles |  | https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/ |
| Biology | ✅ Unpin | https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230 |
| Board Games | ✅ Unpin | https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2048 |
| Chemistry | ✅ Unpin | https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5077 |
| Christianity | ✅ Unpin | [Is Christianity.SE a OP's Gets it or Community Gets it community?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/is-christianity-se-a-ops-gets-it-or-community-gets-it-community) |
| Code Golf | ✅ Unpin | https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23854/ |
| Code Review | ✅ Keep Pin | https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10719 |
| Coffee | ✅ Unpin | https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1253 |
| Computational Science |  | https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/ |
| Cross Validated |  | https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/ |
| Drupal Answers |  | https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/ |
| Earth Science | ✅ Unpin | https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1932/ |
| Economics |  | https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2151 |
| English Language Learners |  | https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514 |
| English Language & Usage | Keep Pin | https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15144 |
| French |  | https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/833 |
| Gardening | Keep pin | https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ |
| German Language | Unpin | https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1653 |
| Genealogy & Family History |  | https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3522/19 |
| GIS | ✅ Unpin | https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5303 |
| Graphic Design | ✅ Unpin | https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3779/41100 |
| History |  | https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4311/1401 |
| Interpersonal Skills | ✅ Keep pin | https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4038 |
| Judaism | ✅ Unpin | https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708 |
| Language Learning |  | https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/720 |
| Literature |  | https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1602 |
| Math | ✅ Unpin | https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/ |
| Matter Modeling | 50/50 | https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/ |
| Meta Stack Exchange |  | [Do we want accepted answers unpinned on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370716) |
| Movies | Unpin | https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780 |
| Music |  | https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3781 |
| Parenting | Keep Pin | https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/ |
| Pets | ✅ Unpin | https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/please-vote-do-we-want-to-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list |
| Physical Fitness | ✅ Unpin | https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865 |
| Physics | ✅ Unpin | https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13811 |
| Politics | ✅ Unpin | [Should accepted answers still be pinned to the top of the list of answers?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5976) |
| Politics Meta | Unpin | [Should accepted answers be pinned to the top on meta?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6021) |
| Project Management |  | https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/896 |
| Puzzling | ✅ Keep Pin | https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7230/ |
| Quantum Computing |  | https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/ |
| RPG | 50/50 | https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/ |
| Sci-fi and Fantasy | ✅ Unpin | https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13478/ |
| Seasoned Advice |  | https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/ |
| Skeptics |  | https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4786 |
| Spanish Language | ✅ Keep Pin | https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4435 |
| Sports | ✅ Unpin | https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/ |
| Stack Overflow (Portuguese) | ✅ Unpin | https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8662/ |
| Superuser | ✅ Keep Pin | https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14531 |
| TeX |  | https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8841 |
| UNIX & Linux | ✅ Unpin | https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/ |
| Veganism & Vegetarianism |  | https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366 |
| Webmasters | ✅ Unpin | https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1728 |
| Workplace | Keep Pin | [Any thoughts on unpinning the accepted answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6975) |
| Worldbuilding | 50/50 | https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8441 |
| Stack Overflow in Spanish | ✅ Unpin | https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5273/10 |
| Stack Overflow in Russian | ✅ Unpin | https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11766/6 |
| Stack Overflow in Japanese | ✅ Unpin | https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3641/78 |

#### Sites that want to *remove* the pin

- Ask Ubuntu
- Astronomy
- Aviation
- Biology
- Board Games
- Chemistry
- Christianity
- Code Golf
- Earth Science
- German Language
- GIS
- Judaism
- Math
- Movies
- Pets
- Physical Fitness
- Physics
- Politics
- Science Fiction and Fantasy
- Sports
- Stack Overflow em Português
- UNIX & Linux
- Webmasters
- Stack Overflow in Spanish
- Stack Overflow in Russian
- Stack Overflow in Japanese

#### Sites that want to *keep* the pin

- Arqade
- Ask Ubuntu Meta
- Code Review
- English Language & Usage
- Gardening
- Interpersonal Skills
- Parenting
- Puzzling
- Super User
- The Workplace

Comment: @nicolas-chabanovsky before we go too far in a random direction, is there a format (and set of values) that'd work best for you here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you very much for setting the table. It is perfect! We will need any way to either keep it pinned or unpin it for all sites and process the rest manually. Having a table is a great way to do so!

Comment: At what point are decisions edited into this as "final"? Do we wait for a member of each site to do so, or do we say that after X days, with a margin of Y, it's decided?

Comment: It's interesting that pinning is being used in this meta question to place a relevant meta answer at the top of the thread, showing the value of this behaviour for certain types of questions.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I would imagine that depends on the site and the usual level of activity in their relevant meta sites.

Comment: Sep 19th sounded like the deadline to me, but these sound like settings in software, so... [6-8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/307535)?

Comment: The pin-to-top behaviour can be useful, but assigning that behaviour to all questions and decided by one arbitrary user is not. Bringing it back for posts e.g. tagged [tag:feature-request] on meta sites only would be a nice move, but ultimately not relevant here.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Should MathOverflow be listed here?

Comment: @DavidRoberts If the community wants the change it would be nice to know about it and have the site on the list.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky as a moderator of Spanish.SE I would like to ask that both the change to "all sites" and the "per-site exceptions" are applied close to each other in time. If "unpin" wins and the sites that requested to keep the pin see that they get "unpin" anyway and have to wait 6-8 months to get back the old behavior that they never asked to be removed, they are going to be quite annoyed. This is important in our community because we have already lost more than one long-term, high-rep user due to the >2-year wait for 3-vote close, which we still haven't got.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky on the first 6 links I see the question titles but further down the list I only see URL addresses. When I click on the edit tab, suddenly all the addresses change into titles. Is this a bug? Is my browser at fault? No one else has mentioned it so maybe I need to update my operating system (Yosemite) :((

Comment: @Mari-LouA It looks the same for me: a few first links get rendered into text and all the following as links.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  Ah, so it's a status by design :) Thanks for replying, I guess everyone else knows about this *feature*.

Comment: Maybe https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/307535 explains the link text conversion?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky do the checkmarks indicate that the decision has been implemented?

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, correct. I am going through the list and updating site settings now.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky On physics, the vote tally is 21 o 17. That's too close. Please un-implement this on Physics.SE for now. Likewise on Sports.SE, it's 5 to 3. Please don't change the behavior of the entire site somewhat permanently based on such little consensus.

Comment: @user1271772 That seems like something to bring up on the respective site meta posts, instead of editing out the decision conveyed by the creators of those posts on behalf of their sites.

Comment: No Russian Stackoverflow as well...

Comment: @aepot ironic given that Nicolas has been a member of for 11 years :) [funny that I did not notice till now too] On a more serious note, the table was missing some of the sites that were manually added later - I'll edit RuSO in shortly. Any pointers as to the discussion post there? Seeing SO interface in Russian is a bit confusing to me, so I failed to find the post

Comment: I failed too, sorry then. @NicolasChabanovsky any chance to push the discussion to RU SO Meta?

Comment: @aepot I suppose you can start it too - it does not have to be a mod or CM bringing up - just link it here afterwards, and one of the folks following the post will edit the site in

Comment: @user1271772 Please remember that votes on these meta posts aren't locked. The votes on Physics were far more in favor when the change was made. You're assuming that the scores have always been what they are now and finding fault. It wasn't this close when Nicolas changed the site setting. Also, we probably should only consider upvotes, not both up and down. Editing out the current status is not OK.

Comment: @aepot Please feel free to start the discussion yourself - the CMs will not be starting discussions about whether to pin or unpin accepted answers on each site - the site must have the discussion themselves.

Comment: @user1271772 I think this situation has only two possible outcomes: We either pin or unpin, there is nothing in between. Moving forward with the most upvoted decision, even if the delta is little, seems better than doing it in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Catija I see. BTW, Nicolas posted this one meanwhile he fluently knows Russian. Personally, I have no internal reasons to post this myself. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky After 13+ years of the entire network working one way, you'll change something "even if the delta is little", meaning that even if a site with 5000 users votes 5 to 4 after far less than 1 month of discussion and voting, that they want the change? Alright, as long as you (fairly quickly) change it back when it becomes 5 to 6 the other way around. Will you?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Sites with tens of thousands of users are getting maybe 30 people voting on the change. I think the more conservative approach would be leaving things the way the vast majority of users are used to until there is a significant consensus to change them.

Comment: +1 to the comment by @ColleenV (even though I disagreed with their view that users with high enough rep shouldn't be allowed to earn the privilege to pin their accepted answer to the top, for sites that decide to unpin). I'll add to Colleen's comment and say "significant consensus" is subjective. [Sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Polling_is_not_a_substitute_for_discussion) "votes" aren't counted at all and only the arguments themselves are. On MSE there's [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233908/391772) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/391772).

Comment: @ColleenV But that's what they're doing now, by not changing the default behaviour unless a site specifically asks. What constitutes a consensus to change has been left to individual sites to decide, and SE just executes the decision. Any dispute regarding the decision taken by a site can be brought up on that site itself.

Comment: @user1271772 exactly, it is subjective, so SE is not deciding how much is enough. The decisions are conveyed by the individual sites based on whatever criteria they deem fit.

Comment: @GoodDeeds what you're saying in your last two comments is not exactly true though. I know at least one site where the decision of a mod was not honored (at least so far) by the CM who reviewed it and switched it from "status-review" to "status-deferred".

Comment: @GoodDeeds A slim margin of a fraction of the users doesn’t warrant changing anything. That’s my only point. If there is a significant consensus like there has been for a number of sites, then the community has spoken and it should be changed or not according to the consensus.

Answer (score 138):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

If the accepted post has score equal to another post please show the accepted post upper.

Suppose there are 3 answers for a post say A, B and C. Let A score be 1, B and C score be 0. Let C be the accepted answer.

[image]

Like you can see then if votes order is choosen then the post will be in order A>B>C. But I guess it should be made A>C>B. If 2 or most post have same score out of which one answer has been accepted then that accepted answer should be upper than the remaining answer because since OP accepted it, the accepted answer might be more helpful than the other answers at same score.

Comment: I prefer the pseudo random order, since OP is the least qualified to know which answer should be preferred, as the SO experiment showed.

Comment: @Braiam The experiment was not designed to test that scenario.

Comment: @Braiam which experiment?

Comment: @JitendraSingh https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411192/792066

Comment: @Tomerikoo Votes more accurately reflect the best answer because more people agree with it, but if the OP accepts it, that means they at least somewhat think that the answer is helpful.  As the experiment shows, votes are better, but accepted should at least be a tiebreaker...

Comment: The ‘‘whole premise of this change’’ is that the checkmark shouldn’t be a green vote-hammer that counts as an infinite number of votes and even disrupts the other sort orders (active and oldest).  Jitendra Singh’s request is that the checkmark should count as half a vote for sorting purposes, which seems more than reasonable, considering that it counts as 1½ votes for rep purposes.

Comment: Acceptance as a tie-breaker seems very reasonable.  After all, we have a piece of data that says this answer was useful to someone, so we may as well use it.  It's not unknown to have several answers with the same low score of 0 or 1, so letting one that was some use float to the top seems right

Comment: @Braiam when op asks for solution, he is one who checks if it works, so for some sites for OP problem, they can be a judge. For a place like worldbuilding it is exactly as you say it - they usually do not know and they can't test and accepting is just additional cookie given to one who answered it, personally crafted by OP.

Comment: @MolbOrg you have way too much faith in OP. OP have accepted answers that don't work, and didn't work. They can accept an answer for any reason, including no reason. Acceptance is just a way that sites can bootstrap themselves, since it isn't a privilege. Nothing more.

Comment: But mostly good experienced users generally accepted the answer most helpful to them. In your question did you randomly accepted any answer @Braiam?

Comment: @JitendraSingh haven't you noticed that >99% of the questions are asked by new users? Maybe you should consider that in your argument.

Comment: @Braiam I do not, I'm from worldbuilding, I have seen stuff, lol, and was about to add that they can accept for any reason but cut it for length of the comment and it bite me back. As myself accepted few answers just for the attempt to help me. I'm all in for the feature, so do support your comment as well, just wish it be a tiny bit more objective, so added it as a note. The thing is just additional 15 free internet points, and personal op cookie, for whatever reason - and nothing more, no practical value whatsoever. Regularly googled answers with few votes which were exactly what I needed

Comment: @Braiam “*They can accept an answer for any reason, including no reason.*” And what’s the difference to upvotes? I have seen answer containing a non-working solution with tons of upvotes. Under normal circumstances, the OP should be the one who is motivated to *actually try* the posted solution while it happens very often that the other people, not having the problem, upvote an answer that just looks convincing. Granted, I’ve seen non-working answers with the checkmark too, don’t know what’s going on with those questioners, but still, SO considers question to be *solved* in that case.

Comment: @Holger the fact that all our votes are equal. I can vote only once per post and on any post. The asker gets two votes on any answer to their question and would have a different effect on the post if this is implemented. That's the difference from the acceptance vote and regular votes. That's why I don't want the acceptance vote to do anything other than be an extra rep reward for the answerer and nothing else.

Comment: @Braiam I agree with your point too. Every feature-request has its own advantages and disadvantages. Some will agree and some not. Let the SE team whether they want this or not

Comment: @Braiam Acceptance seems comparable to an upvote (especially when the asker doesn't have enough rep to upvote). Putting the accepted answer first among equally voted answers is not saying the asker knows better than anyone else, it's closer to saying acceptance is a positive signal (however big or small) and an answer with 1 additional positive signal is more likely to be better than an equivalent answer without that signal.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "Acceptance seems comparable to an upvote" but it's not. It gives a higher reward for the vote, it can be only cast once per question, only on answers, give a reward to the asker and can't be cast by anyone other than the asker. It is very orthogonal to votes also in the sense that you don't need any privilege to be able to cast them. Mixing it with the other ranking mechanism when so many fundamental differences exist is irrational. At least the other voting mechanism are gated and only available once you've shown some modicum of experience with the site.

Comment: For 1 or 2 votes, acceptance is still a fairly strong signal. For many votes, it's unlikely for answers to have equal votes, and when they do, how we sort them seems negligible. [2/2]

Comment: @NotThatGuy Here's the kick, once you introduce it into the ranking mechanism you are saying that they are similar/fulfill similar purpose. If there's a 0.00001% extra of a vote, it's still something that no one else have access to.

Comment: We have decided to implement this change and will allow the accepted answer to be the tie-breaker when it has the same score as other answers. We will update this post when the work is completed.

Comment: This has been implemented. When sorting by votes, the Accepted Answer will be sorted above other answers that have the same number of votes.

Answer (score 72):

This is a modified copy of [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411509/369434) to the related question on Meta Stack Overflow.

---

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Unpinning the accepted answer is a good change for the majority of SE sites I imagine.

However, I would still very much like a clear indication (near the top of the question) that an answer has been accepted and offer a link to jump to it. As it is now, when viewing the question, there is no indication that an answer has been accepted unless you scroll through the answers (if there are other answers that have more votes).

(Something similar has already been suggested in comments by @ColleenV and @V2Blast.)

Perhaps a link next to the sorting buttons, something like:

[image: Suggested link to jump to the accepted answer]

Comment: Especially if we include the date: "Go to the answer that was accepted on DATE"

Comment: I think this could potentially be especially helpful to the asker, who may want to find the answer they accepted to review it or compare it to other answers or to get some clear signal that they actually have accepted an answer (in case they forgot whether they did).

Comment: We will explore this request as part of the next phase of the Outdated Answers project. We are considering other changes to the Sort menu, and will include this idea in what we design and test.

Comment: You could reverse the same idea on cases where pinning is on, and make the link say "Go to highest voted answer" instead, on these cases. Also, it might be useful to have a URL fragment like "#accepted" that makes the browser skip to wherever is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 50):

Stack Overflow is probably the site where the concept of accepted answers makes the most sense, and even there I think pinning the accepted answer is overall harmful in the end. For non-technical sites the accepted answer concept is often less meaningful simply because it is harder for the asker to evaluate answers, especially when the questions aren't about fixing a problem. On SO many questions can be objectively evaluated even if you have less knowledge than the answerers, e.g. now the code compiles or now I get the correct result. For more "fuzzy" subjects the asker might just accept the answer that best fits their preconceived notions, or simply the one that sounds and looks the most impressive.

For this reason I would argue that the default should be not to pin the accepted answer to the top. And any site that likes to do that different can request changing this back. If you are convinced that this is the right choice for Stack Overflow, unpinning by default is the right choice for the network as well. This is not one of the cases where SO is the outlier that needs special handling.

Comment: *And any site that likes to do that different can request changing this back.* Extremely unlikely that such requests would actually end up actioned in a timely manner, just saying. But I definitely see your point for SO.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Why do you think that? This should be a site setting that the CMs have access to and can change in a minute. Provided the request was status-reviewed on the child meta, I don't think this would take more than a day or two to change.

Comment: It makes sense, but how will you convince the *don't move my cheese* folks?

Comment: @Catija: We don't have access to your internal discussions. We don't *know* which things are "a CM can change that in five minutes" and which things are "six to eight weeks."

Comment: @Kevin sure... but that doesn't excuse such an extreme statement as what Sonic said. Particularly since the question here specifically indicates that per-site configuration is possible.

Answer (score 47):

I agree with the change, thanks for doing this.

For users who want to keep the old behaviour, I've written a small userscript, Accepted Answer Pinner ([direct installation link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/accepted-answer-pinner/accepted-answer-pinner.user.js) – [Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/9144/34061)). It pins the accepted answer back on top, unless it's a self-answer that wouldn't qualify for pinning in the old situation.

Comment: As you are a moderator on ELL, could you please post something on meta asking for users' feedback?

Comment: @Mari-LouA great suggestion, will do once I can use my laptop again (somewhere tomorrow).

Comment: Thank you! It's a pity that meta is so quiet on ELL but maybe, and hopefully, this announcement will get users excited and if it doesn't at least we can direct confused regulars to a specific post. Thanks :))))

Comment: +1 You should make a script that allows one to follow users because I have read through some of the posts and value your input. Basically, you make the StackExchange a well-reasoned space.

Answer (score 41):

Not every moderator or high-rep user participates on Stack Exchange Meta, and not every hi-rep or engaged user participates on their child site.

Nevertheless, I think the option to unstick the accepted answer from its pole position should be discussed by each individual meta site. **Please feature this post and communicate this proposal to all the moderators across the network.** I think it's possible that many moderators, especially on smaller sites, might be oblivious to this announcement.

Comment: Or at least make this post [featured]. I think that any post that says _"We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site"_ should **most definitely** be featured. But I'm not sure why the staff is a bit conservative with the [featured] tag. I've requested that similar posts be featured before and they were not.

Comment: @41686d6564 I think there's a good chance of it being featured as long as the announcement is not downvoted.

Comment: Some of the meta sites are pretty much dead and little to no discussion will happen regardless of how much they want it to.

Comment: @JoeW  That maybe true but how else will you inform users from smaller communities who never ever visit Meta?  At least communities will have been notified on their  meta site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If the meta site gets almost no traffic does asking about it there do anything? The problem is you have meta sites where question getting dozens of views is typical as almost no one out side of a very small group ever visits it.

Comment: If users choose to ignore their site's meta, and notices on the bulletboard i.e. `featured on meta` and `hot meta posts`, then they have only themselves to blame if changes to the system occur without their knowing or seal of approval.

Comment: How exactly does putting a question on a child meta that gets no traffic change anything from putting asking the question here? My point was that there are sites where users don't care about meta at all and trying to ask this question on every single meta would be a waste of time.

Comment: This isn't about people not seeing it because they don't use meta but the fact that if meta isn't used the post won't get any feedback (or enough feedback to be valuable) and provide no value or decision.

Answer (score 27):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Keep the accepted answer pinned on meta sites

Oftentimes, on meta sites, the behavior of pinning the accepted answer to the top is preferred:

- Answers can be different opinions in a discussion, and accepting the one that is eventually the community's consensus or is the one that eventually gets implemented will make that fact clear to others reading the question, especially if that one isn't the one with the highest number of votes.
- A question may receive an official response from the team, which may not be the highest-voted answer, usually simply because other community answers were posted first, but in some cases may be due to the answer being negatively-received. However, it's still preferred to have it pinned to the top so that others can more easily see the official response.

Please don't unpin the accepted answer on meta sites, at least.

If there are concerns that the wrong answer (not representative of community consensus) would be accepted, then another, separate feature, to allow moderators and staff to change the accepted answer on meta sites, should be implemented. Personally, though, in my experience, that happens a very tiny minority of the time, and in the rare cases where it's a problem, a developer [can change the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) so it remains pinned even if it's later voted out.

Comment: I see what you're getting at here but I don't consistently feel like this is actually true. The thing is, with the accept still being the choice of the asker, you'll have inconsistent behavior. Some will accept  the staff answer or the consensus answer while others will choose what they liked best at the time and might actually be downvoted or disliked - other times you'll accept the consensus at the time, which later changes and the asker is now MIA. For metas, honestly, I feel like we would benefit from a different system entirely but I don't think that opting to pin or not is that change.

Comment: What about here on MSE?  I can think of quite a few accepted answers that have been staff-posted, accepted, and then downvoted into double/triple digits.

Comment: @Catija I've seen that happen, but in the questions I've read, that's a tiny minority. The vast majority of the time, users accept the staff answer or the consensus answer. It's an even smaller minority on the site metas.

Comment: @Ollie I still think that such answers should be pinned. Regardless of score, they're still official responses nonetheless. It also makes it easier for later answers to argue against the reasons in the official response. Also, again, that's a tiny minority.

Comment: My view is the exact opposite: **don't pin accepted answers to the top on meta sites**. It's really unfair to give one user so much say over which answer appears first, when it's an issue of community policy. I've seen cases where a meta OP accepts a low-voted answer and we have to remind people that the community consensus is the *second* answer in the list. See [this SFF meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9928/31394), referencing [acceptance vs consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5263/31394) and [this on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85095/278659).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Staff have the ability to change the accepted answer; it's done on the recent feature changes post here so the current answer is pinned even though the asker is deleted. If you're running into one such case, just ask staff to do so there, so that the one that *does* represent consensus is pinned regardless of future voting.

Comment: @Sonic I don't think it is (or should be) worth bothering staff for every time a trolly OP accepts the wrong answer on meta, or consensus changes after the OP disappears, or an inexperienced OP doesn't understand how acceptance works, or all the other possible scenarios. In fact I don't approve of staff meddling with acceptance at all, and I imagine they too only want to do so in extremely rare and special situations.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yeah... If we have the ability to do that, I don't know about it and I don't think I actually can do it. I have a huge aversion to ever changing the accepted answer because that's an inappropriate choice in most cases.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've edited the answer to request that the ability be given to regular mods and regular staff. (Also, corrections: it can only be done by devs, and the asker isn't deleted but hasn't been seen in a long time, but the same reasons still apply.)

Comment: @Catija As I said, it's extremely rare that it would want to be done, since the vast majority of the time, people accept the official or consensus answer, and in most remaining cases, don't accept an answer anyway. It's only in the very rare cases where a non-representative answer gets accepted, and where you'd want to use this ability. My answer requests that this be made easier for those rare cases, and also points out that it's already possible (by developers), so that it's resolved for all cases, even the rare ones.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have on occasion seen belligerent questions get self answered and self accepted with belligerent answers, and we'd rather not have the super negative answer pinned.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that's actually something we already control for since accepted self answers don't pin.

Comment: @Catija Well how bout that. Learn something new every day.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/last-seen-time-appears-on-google-and-se-profile-pages-and-should-be-removed) on Meta where "the" answer has been recently accepted (and thus pinned). It will never receive the most votes, both because the answer/resolution is unpopular and because it is years/decades newer than the other answers. But it is the "status completed" Answer and should probably be at the top...

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338270/355458) is an example on MSE where a staff response *should* be pinned at the top (and even involved some ...unpopular shenanigans to make sure that it was), but won't be once this goes live

Comment: You probably want to separate your proposals, this will lead to murky voting.

Comment: @Akixkisu The last paragraph isn't a proposal. The second sentence says that that's unnecessary.

Comment: Perhaps a "pin answer to top" power for diamond moderators on their meta would be a useful feature. Then we do not have arbitrary users steering the discussion, while still having the option to record the "accepted" proposal out of a list of proposals to some policy change.

Comment: This may be more a case for a different feature "staff can pin specific answers in meta" to force official policy responses to be at the top, rather than going by accepted - when talking about meta you get a lot of opinion involved and there's a much less clear definition for what's "best" in some cases, you either get the consensus at the time accepted (which can change) or the answer that the asker is biased towards (regardless of group consensus or staff response)

Comment: Marked this as status-completed to indicate that keeping the accepted answer pinned on Meta sites is the default behavior and we don't plan to change it. Each Meta site can opt to unpin the accepted answer at its own discretion per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/349251).

Answer (score 22):

> Please let us know what you think will work best for your site! If you can discuss this question with your community it would be awesome.

[We've already discussed this on Mi Yodeya.](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708)  As of this writing, the question there is +12/−0 and the only answer is +10/−0; both ask for the accepted answer to be unpinned. So **Mi Yodeya wants the accepted answer unpinned**.  Thanks!

Comment: Ask a moderator to set the status-review tag on the site meta question.

Comment: @Braiam thanks. Probably not necessary, since it's already under review, as noted in the question above.

Answer (score 20):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I'll throw in what I suggested on Politics SE: A hybrid model.  Acceptance indicates that "this answer is what the asker was looking for."  On Politics, that can range from "I feel informed" to "This confirms my political beliefs so I like it."

Even so, I think acceptance still has value, but shouldn't be the end-all of the matter.

Adding a site-configurable weight to the acceptance is probably a good compromise feature.  Accepted answers can enjoy top billing until an answer outscores them by a significant margin (e.g. 125%+).  For low-scoring answers this could get distorted but I think that, overall, it lets an asker indicate "this had particular value for me" but allows majorities of presumably knowledgeable people indicate that such an answer may not actually be superior.

Comment: We declined this feature request because we think it is too complicated and won't make a big enough difference in the sort order. We think that [jump to accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369839#369839) accomplishes the same thing and is simpler to understand and implement.

Answer (score 18):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

We've had [some discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7230/do-we-want-to-keep-the-accepted-answer-pinned-to-the-top) over on Puzzling, where there is a definite consensus on keeping accepted answers at the top (i.e., *not* unpinning).

One person looked at some concrete examples, which suggest to me that actually "keep the accepted answer at the top, unless its score is *actually negative* in which case don't" might be a better option (for us) than either "unpin completely" or "leave exactly as is".

Comment: Basically asking for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178439/1017231), then?

Comment: Yup! It does seem like a pretty reasonable option; "has negative score" seems like a more reliable indicator of outright wrongness than "is outscored by another answer". (But this is a thing that will be different on different SE sites; e.g., on SO, it's possible for an answer to be excellent but out of date; it then doesn't deserve to be downvoted into oblivion, but another answer that isn't out of date may well be a better candidate for the top spot. That doesn't really happen on Puzzling where things are more self-contained.)

Comment: We felt that this proposed solution overly complicates things, especially on Meta sites. Accepted answers will either be pinned or unpinned according to each site's preference -- we won't be making exceptions based on negative scores.

Comment: Fair enough! (It doesn't seem like so very much complexity to me, but I haven't looked at the codebase...)

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

To aid sites in deciding what impact this might have, is there some SEDE magic query that would list and/or count questions where this change would alter the answer order?  It would be nice to have local data about the scale of the change.

Comment: [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/1458649/1790665/), by Physics SE user Nihar Karve, seems to do a complete job in this direction.

Comment: ... and [here is an improved version of that query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1458833/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer).

Comment: Marked completed since SEDE queries were posted as comments.

Answer (score 16):

I think choosing between "pinned" and "unpinned" is not good enough. I think "pinning" should be replaced network-wide with something that accomplishes the original goal of pinning the accepted answer with fewer negative side effects and possibly even a slightly improved user experience, instead of either taking away something that some of the community find useful or leaving something in place that causes a negative user experience for some of the community.

According to [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/273494)

> Accepting an answer is important as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question, informs others that your issue is resolved, and **pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first.**

I interpret that to mean the goal of pinning the accepted answer is to make it more visible to future readers. There are ways to accomplish that without forcing readers to see the answer that personally worked best for the question's author before they see the best answer as voted by the community.

I would prefer an easily noticed (but not intrusive) button to bring up the answer the author chose. If there is no accepted answer, the button should not be visible. The checkmark should continue to exist so the accepted answer is still highlighted as I scroll through the answers.

Not only does this put the decision on whether to read the accepted answer first in the hands of the reader, I think it improves the accessibility experience because someone using a screen reader will be able to tell immediately if there is an accepted answer by the presence of the button. If "pinning" can change according to the site, it would be difficult for someone using a screen reader to get directly to the accepted answer (or know whether one exists) on sites that choose not to pin it. I don't have a lot of experience using a screen reader, so I'm just speculating.

I don't know if this solution is the best one, and I would support more elegant alternatives, but it's better than forcing each site to come to a consensus about whether to pin or not to pin.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was planning to write about this but was not sure about the wording. Something like "Jump to accepted answer" would work but might not be the best wording. It's somewhat similar to how other sites have a "Go to solution" link in that it gives a great level of importance to the accepted answer. I still think something like this should be implemented; ideally, while indicating (somehow) that the accepted answer is not THE _correct_ answer.

Comment: This is actually wrong because adding any button to the current UI is more intrusive than a backstage settings solution. Otherwise you're seeing a button on all threads you might not be interested in. Regarding accessibility, in your own words: you're speculating.

Comment: @41686d6564 I try to leave the exact details of the UI to people who are smarter about that stuff than I am :) I had the same qualms about exactly what the button might be labeled or documented as doing. The entire accepted answer concept is just a little bit weird. Naming it something else might make its purpose clearer, but I have no suggestions.

Comment: @ColleenV I was thinking of maybe [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLy9C.png) where the "Show first" row is only shown when sorting by votes. Then, this could either be saved as a setting in the user's preferences or be a one-time thing (like a button) where it defaults to "Highest score" every time. I'm fine with either.

Comment: @41686d6564 I wonder if it should be somewhere else, like closer to the question, so it's clear the author chose it. Like a button under the voting buttons that has nothing to do with sort order, it just pops up the answer the author wants to highlight. One thing that confuses some is that the accepted answer can change. Switching to a "showcase" or "highlight" idea might help that. (the sort order is separated from the question by comments)

Answer (score 14):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Can a setting be included in the user profile to keep the accepted answer pinned to the top? My preference is to have the accepted answer shown first.

Ollie said:

> (...) because it'll work for more people.

Sonic the Hedgehog said:

> (...) this should be a per-site setting, because I'd want to see the accepted answer on the top on some sites but not on others.

Comment: I agree with this one, not because that's my personal choice, but because it'll work for more people.

Comment: If this is implemented on all sites, this should be a per-site setting, because I'd want to see the accepted answer on the top on some sites but not on others.

Comment: I disagree with making this user configurable. This is basic functionality that should work consistently for every user so that we don't have to explain that sometimes it it's pinned and sometimes it's not. If this were an option for changing the color of the checkmark or some sort of aesthetic choice, I would feel differently.

Comment: @ColleenV your argument doesn't hold by that logic we couldn't have any settings at all. Besides changing a setting from default presupposes the user knows what they're doing. E.g. I haven't seen anyone asking why they're using dark theme unaware of having chosen the setting themselves.

Comment: @bad_coder Darkmode is an aesthetic choice, accepted answer behavior is not. See this article for some thoughts on why "make it user configurable" is not always the best answer: http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2008/05/18/preferences-considered-harmful/ There's a difference between a preference and a configuration.

Comment: What ColleenV said. My preference is for some kind of "Zoom to the Accepted Answer" button or link.

Comment: @ColleenV the article and your argument isn't solid because it mixes business logic with presentation. The preference wouldn't overwhelm users and one sort setting doesn't qualify as the nightmare you describe it to be. (I think PM 2Ring's idea less usable that this setting.)

Comment: In case this is declined, or takes too long to be implemented, I threw up a quick user script for doing this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579/295232

Comment: Yes, it could be nice. But also it needs to not forget that se has some google traffic and the descision will have about 10% difference for that traffic. For some places, like puzzling it indeed preferable to keep accepted pinned, for other places pinning has no practical value, and google traffic most likely would preffer higher vote first.

Comment: Proposal based on the above: i) each site to decide its own default setting (_pinned_ or _unpinned_); ii) each user (either at the point of joining the site or else at a specific rep level) to have their own _over-ride_, which can overrule the site's default setting; iii) whenever _pinned_ setting is `false`, include, above the answers, a link to asker's accepted answer

Comment: In favour of making it user configurable: There are already some user toggles to the sorting of answers (by date of answer, by activity, or by votes).  So adding a toggle show accepted answer on top should be available as well.

Comment: We declined this request because we think that consistency on each site is important, and we don't roll items that are so important to the mechanics of the site into individualized user preferences.

Answer (score 14):

Sports SE will use [voting on a meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/accepted-answers-to-pin-or-not-to-pin) to make the decision, or failing sufficient engagement, we can discuss it as a mod team with CMs.

If other sites need a template for this discussion, they are free to use this question and its answers.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've used your template on [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/16685)

Answer (score 13):

[We've discussed this on CGCC](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23854/66833) and have come to the conclusion that we'd *absolutely* like the accepted answer to be unpinned on our site.

Comment: I still absolutely wouldn't!

Comment: @TroyMcClure - I hear you. This is why I've suggested adding a _toggle-switch_ to every user's profile to override the default if they should wish to: [why not give each user the choice to pin or unpin?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369833#369833)

Answer (score 11):

A problem I see with this is the new better answers to an **old** question, e.g. once the Hot Network stampede has subsided. This leaves better or even *the* correct answers buried.

What I thought about before is vote normalization based on Q age. Of course some may want to game such system by answering later, but here's the cool thing: it works the same for downvotes. Call it the anti-[necroing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/necro#Noun) device (i.e. be sure to add to the topic).

Just food for thought. *I'm not really familiar with posting answers on MSE, so let me know if I shouldn't have posted this tangential viewpoint.*

Comment: I think it's fair to say that this is merely the first step. There's a huge amount of discussion going on on MSO around what to do with outdated answers. This was the first (and likely simplest) change. So, yes, I totally agree that in the case of active askers who accept newer, better answers, this is a bit of a loss but that's why this is such a complicated issue - there's no perfect solution that allows for the various participation levels of askers while maintaining the accepted status as an indication of the asker's opinion.

Comment: Alternative sorts is one of the things people have discussed, such as sorting by recent voting rather than all-time voting. So this isn't the end of the discussion, merely the beginning, I think. :)

Comment: From the 2021-07-21 blog post *[The Loop: Our Community & Public Platform Roadmap for Q3 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/29/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q3-2021/)* (my emphasis): *"We will also be exploring the concept of a Trending sort that* ***weights recent votes more heavily*** *than older votes."*. [Corresponding MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368049/mse-feedback-post-feedback-on-q3-2021-community-and-public-platform-roadmap)."

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A point raised in the comments by ColleenV is that Google displays the accepted answer in the snippet. My understanding is that this is automatially done by getting the answer with acceptedAnswer set on it (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage#question)). Will this change for this experiment to be the top answer, or is that outside of the scope?

Comment: Google does whatever it wants so how they do things is off topic here.

Comment: This is an excellent question! I didn't know that SE basically gave which answer was accepted to Google directly; I always assumed it was automatically parsed.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Google has the ultimate say over what displays in that top box and in search snippets, but it uses Stack Overflow's ["context clues"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop) (aka Microdata) to determine if it's worth showing at all. The reason why I think it's not off-topic is because we're ultimately changing what people are going to look at the most: the first answer

Comment: @RobertLongson That's an incorrect understanding of what's being asked here– Stack Exchange is *structuring* the data that describes a given QA page in a certain way so that it's easy for Google (and other engines) to parse and understand. SE is currently setting the *OP accepted answer* as the "right"/ accepted answer in that schema; whether or not SE will begin sending the highest scored answer in this place instead could have a real impact, and is very on-topic.

Comment: @zcoop98 that's not correct. SE is doing nothing, but describing the content. Google is the one that should be able to select the highest scoring one. Sadly it seems that the score isn't included in the schema.org behavior, only total upvotes and total downvotes (I don't have a good idea of how this should work, probably a new property called totalscore).

Comment: Thank you for that link. I see that ["accepted answer" is a property of Question](https://schema.org/Question), so SE doesn't have a way to suggest an order for the answer list to a search engine; even if we fiddled with the answer that was marked as "accepted", I assume the interpretation of that would be up to the site using the data. Although it does look like we could [pass a list](https://schema.org/acceptedAnswer) instead of a single answer. Could we send both the "accepted" and the highest voted if we wanted to? (web stuff is not my area)

Comment: Sometime after reading this, I ran across the official Google tool for testing what a given page sends back as a schema: Google's [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results). Testing this page, for instance, confirms a few things: 1. SE is sending Google _all_ answers (accepted as such, and all others under "suggested"); 2. "upvoteCount" is sent with _total score_, not the actual upvote count; 3. all "suggested answers" are sent with their score, meaning that Google does have a way to rank them.

Comment: @zcoop98 is correct re: what we already do. We will change our logic so that if the accepted answer is unpinned on a site, we will make the highest scoring answer be the acceptedAnswer in Google's schema

Comment: This has been completed. From now, for sites where the accepted answer is unpinned, the top voted answer on the page will be given the `acceptedAnswer` schema notation. In the case of a tie, tie goes to an actual accepted answer, and all others will get `suggestedAnswer`.

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

[Right now, we are discussing this issue on Math.SE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/do-we-want-accepted-answers-unpinned-on-math-se) I posted an answer there, but I think it is relevant here also.

I think the best solution would be to allow users to choose between sorting strictly by the number of votes, and putting the accepted answer at the top. Right now, there are three ways of sorting the answers: active, oldest, and votes. I would like to add a fourth option that ignores whether an answer has been accepted or not. (What this option should be called is another question.) As before, the site should "remember" the option that you used last time.

Comment: I think the best place would then be to have this as a setting on your user profile, rather then add another element to the question UI.

Comment: @Luuklag: It's good that you've brought up. [Judging by some of the other comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369619?noredirect=1#comment1233274_369570), it seems that there is not a consensus on whether it should be a setting on your user profile, or a fourth filter on each thread. Personally, I don't have a strong preference either way—I just users to be able to *choose* how they sort the answers.

Comment: I think that at least the discussion applies to the default setting, even if we have such an option. I'm assuming that the initial problem of "accept bias" affects mostly users that don't care with this type of settings, so at least changing the default behaviour can be a step forward (sorry I'm hijacking a post related to a community that I don't participate actively, but I'm thinking in general terms, not directly related to Math.SE)

Comment: @Bacco: Yes, I agree that we should still discuss what the default setting is (especially since there are unregistered users/new users who won't know how to change the way to sort the answers). I just think that whichever choice is made, the ability to choose between sorting strictly by votes, and putting the accepted answer at the top, is preserved.

Comment: We declined this request because we think that [jump to accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369839#369839) accomplishes the same thing and is simpler to understand and implement.

Answer (score 9):

In Stack Overflow in Portuguese we opened a Meta post discussing the matter.

[Devemos mudar a ordenação das respostas, não afixando a resposta aceita antes das demais?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8662)

Votes up are "Unpin", down are "Keep pinning".

Currently we have:

- 12 + 1 votes to unpin <sup>1</sup>
- 1 to keep pinned

<sup>1</sup> The "+ 1" vote to "unpin" is per the last post line (OP can't vote, but stated he wants the change too).

The "unpin" is active now, and the score had no recent changes.

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

*Accepted post is pinned second, if it's not the top-scoring answer*.

My thought process:

1. Sometimes accepted answers are underrated in terms of voting, especially in relation to Fastest Gun in the West, Hot Network Questions, and answers to old questions (slow, but well-thought-out answers => fewer upvotes).
2. However, sometimes the most upvoted answer is indeed far better than the accepted answer (or perhaps the accepted answer is flat-out wrong).

I like this approach because it's so simple, and it has the property that "accepted answer" + "most upvoted answer" remain the top two answers (in some order).

(This was originally [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?page=1&tab=votes#comment1234565_369568) since I didn't put much thought into it at the time, but Mari-Lou A proposed [making it an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?page=1&tab=votes#comment1235238_369568).  There's still some boundary cases that need ironing out, e.g. two equal-score top-scoring answers vs. accepted answer.)

Comment: I like this, and maybe add some labels to the two answers like "top voted answer" and "accepted answer" so users know why they are both pinned?

Comment: I think giving the accepted answer some added visibility, but not top billing makes a lot of sense. It would be worth running an experiment on at least. If the top and accepted answer have the same score, we should do what we already do for other answers—flip a coin for the order.

Comment: I had the same thought, except that up to two higher-voted answers could appear above the accepted one. Votes are more important, but the accepted answer shouldn't be completely buried.

Comment: We declined this request because we think that [jump to accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369839#369839) accomplishes the same thing and is simpler to understand and implement.

Answer (score 7):

Our vote at [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) [What is our stance on "Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers"?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11726/44723) features a great variety of answers.

Until we reached the first cutoff period on September 19th, our position expressed in [Doppelgreener's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11728/44723) was by a significant margin in favour of unpinning the accepted answer.

Until September 24th, the voting remained in favour of unpinning accepted answers. On that day, Doppelgreener declared in an edit to align her position with the opposing views while keeping her initial answer intact. This edit was the first edit to her answer after September 9th.

In particular, her views aligned thereafter with [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11750/44723), first posted on September 14th, that steadily gained support at the same time. After that, the voting trend changed to have an influx of negative votes on Doppelgreener's answer - as of now, KRyan's answer sits at an only slightly lower score than hers.

[The first answer, posted by Screamline](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11727/44723), is against unpinning the accepted answer. As of now, it is the answer with the fourth-highest score. Our, as of now, second highest-scoring [answer, posted by Thomas Markov](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11734/44723), gives insight into various statistics.

We feature our discussion on meta until October 14th. We first featured it shortly after KRyan added their answer.

The top scores are currently about 50/50. Doppelgreener's answer has the highest participation of currently 48 votes, KRyan's answer has 35 votes (this answer had six fewer days to accumulate initial votes available to the other two), and Screamline's answer has 31 votes.

We concluded our vote with a slight majority of votes [in favour of unpinning accepted answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11728/44723), at 36 votes,  which, however, also includes 15 downvotes bringing it to the score of 21. The minority vote [in favour of pinning accepted answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11750/44723) ends at 31 upvotes and only 9 downvotes, scoring 22. In conclusion, we remain at a 50/50 score with no clear consensus. So we continue with the status quo, which is the old default of pinning accepted answers until we decide to revote.

Comment: Seems to be fairly strongly in favor of unpinning, though. That top answer outscores the next-highest "keep pinned" answer by 3x. And that's without considering the massive misunderstanding of how answering/the SE model works by some of the major "keep pinned" proponents evidenced in their answers and follow-up comments.

Comment: We've just featured this meta post yesterday, and picked up new answers since doing so, so RPG.SE's discussion is still ongoing and not something I'd call settled.

Answer (score 7):

The **Mathematics SE** community is in favor of unpinning accepted answers (judging by the response to the statement "[I am in favor of ordering answers by number of votes only](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34077/468350).")

Comment: In the immediate aftermath of the meta discussion you link, there were no compelling counter-arguments to unpinning presented.  A few days ago (when I first saw the meta question), I posted such a counter-argument, and it has seen strong support since then.  (Ironically, I think the post itself embodies the counter-point it describes.)  I think in light of the support my answer has received, it is worth re-opening this issue and presenting the counterpoints to let the MSE community vote on, before committing to unpinning accepted answers.

Answer (score 7):

We've [discussed this on Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5077/does-the-community-want-the-accepted-answers-to-be-pinned-to-the-top?cb=1). The only answer is by one of the highest-rep members and a moderator, with a score of +10. **The general consensus is to unpin the accepted answer i.e. we support this proposed change.**

Some of the reasons given there, which I think would apply equally well to some other sites too -

1. The OP may not be the best judge of answers. This can happen if they themselves have a limited knowledge of the subject (as in the case of many students who frequent the Science sites, me included), and some of them hastily accept the first answer and never come back.
2. The number of votes is an indicator of which answer the community, as a whole, believes to be the most useful. The opinion of the *whole* community is certainly more likely to be a better judge of answers than a *single person's* accept-tick.

Answer (score 6):

The issue with the Accepted Answer is about what Stack Overflow is and how it is intended to be used.

There are 2 possible ways to think about Stack Overflow:

1. A help-desk where someone asks a question and gets help from the community. Accepted Answer makes a lot of sense here because you let people that OP has found a solution and no longer needs help.
2. Wikipedia in Q/A format, of user-generated question. That is what SO is in practice. Here an Accepted Answer doesn't make sense because answers are not truly meant to help the OP in particular. The fact that OP does get help is tangential to the site's purposes and is merely useful because it **entices** people to generate content by asking questions for others to answer. The real goal is to help visitors who come from Google or other search engines.

When SO was new and little-known, and didn't have a critical mass of existing solutions and accumulated upvotes, it was 1) and Accepted Answer made sense, but it eventually became 2) and Accepted Answer was no longer needed.

Answer (score 6):

Would you please post a link to a [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) Query, which would list the Q&As (on a given site) where the accepted answer is not also the top-voted answer?

I think it would be helpful, when deciding, to see examples of which topics are affected by this decision.

Comment: Here is a SEDE query posted in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1233649) by [User E.P.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/184688/e-p): [Questions with accepted answer pinned above highest scoring answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1458833).

Comment: And here is that same SEDE query, but then sorted by votes difference: https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1462401/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer

Comment: I would also make sure questions where the accepted answer has a score equal to other answers as well.

Answer (score 6):

#### Ask Ubuntu

We [discussed on our meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19728/should-we-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list) whether to have the accepted answer unpinned or not.

Most people voted in favour of unpinning the accepted answer from the top, it seems.

A relevant concern that was strongly expressed was about obsolete answers appearing ahead of newer ones. A [very popular answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19731/527764) proposed a solution to that instead of directly addressing the question of whether to unpin. [One answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19730/527764) said that an *advantage* of pinning the accepted answer to the top was that the OP could change the accept if the old answer became obsolete. (I upvoted the answer even though I do very much want accepted answers to be unpinned). My opinion is that this rarely happens; [another answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19740/527764) argued that it's more likely that an obsolete answer is pinned at the top while more up to date answers, often with more votes, are stuck below, and I feel the same, but it's hard to be sure (on our site, [more than 9000 questions have an answer that outscores the accepted one](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/1457743/questions-whose-accepted-answer-is-outscored-by-another-answer), but I do not know, for example, how many of them are newer than the accepted answer by a margin of years).

I completely share the concern with the problem of obsolete answers, but I think that accept pinning, to the extent that it might mitigate that problem rather than exacerbating it, is a very weak mechanism, and I hear that better solutions are in the pipeline somewhere. If that is the case and we are going to have some way to deal with obsolete answers more effectively than we can with current tools, then I think all concerns about unpinning can be considered addressed and we can go ahead with it.

#### Ask Ubuntu Meta

We [separately discussed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19733/should-we-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-on-meta/) whether or not to unpin accepted answers on meta and nobody disagreed with my opinion that we should leave them pinned. Some folks even upvoted my answer about it, so I guess they agree.

#### TL;DR

Unpin on main and keep pin on meta, please, and thanks a lot for asking <3

Answer (score 4):

Anti-[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

**Do not reintroduce the accept vote into any ranking mechanism.**

We've already removed some of the most insidious unbalance that the accept vote brings on the system. Please make sure none of it is introduced back. The accepted mark has too many benefits that we don't need to add more on top of it.

It gives extra rewards, effectively almost tripling the potential reward that a single user can do for free and that also benefits the user that do it (+15 to the answerer and +2 to the asker), which is unlike bounties. It also removes the question from the unanswered list, which makes sense since the asker doesn't have the privilege to cast an upvote to select their preferred answer (this have in some cases motivated me to upvote a good answer and accept other, just because the accepted one was the first I used).

It also would give unduly preference to a single user vote over the others if reintroduced to affect the order of answers. We don't need a tie-breaking mechanism that would make the selection more complex, as we've been able to live without it when the asker doesn't accept any answer.

Leaving ranking of answers to be only in the power of users that have demonstrated some modicum experience with the site would undoubtedly benefit the content that we are creating here, so that the best answer always stays to the top.

Answer (score 4):

#### Literature Stack Exchange

As one of the moderators on Literature Stack Exchange, I created a [meta question asking whether the community wants accepted answers to be unpinned](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1602/2191). Several people indicated in the chatroom that they have no opinion about the issue. The votes on the meta question suggest a slight preference for **keeping accepted answers pinned at the top**.

It is worth noting that answers on Literature SE don't get outdated over time, unlike answers on Stack Overflow, where validity or relevance can be influenced by technological evolution.

Answer (score 4):

#### Language Learning Stack Exchange

As one of the moderators on Language Learning Stack Exchange, I created a [meta question asking whether the community wants accepted answers to be unpinned](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/720/800). The votes on the meta question suggest a slight preference for **keeping accepted answers pinned at the top**.

It is worth noting that answers on Language Learning SE would rarely get outdated over time, unlike answers on Stack Overflow, where validity or relevance can be influenced by technological evolution.

Answer (score 4):

#### [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

via [voting on Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/20688) decided that **we support unpinning the accepted answer** from the top.

Thus,

- if "by default" the accepted answer is unpinned for all communities, we don't need anything special.
- otherwise, if unpinning requires explicit request, by the means of this message we express one.

Comment: This is controversial, see this comment: https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-list-of-the-answers#comment1967_600

Comment: @user1271772 ok.

Answer (score 4):

#### French Language Stack Exchange

As one of the moderators on French Language Stack Exchange, I created a [meta question asking whether the community wants accepted answers to be unpinned](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/833/11052). The votes on the meta question suggest a preference for **unpinning accepted answers**.

It is worth noting that answers on French Language SE are much less likely to get outdated over time than on Stack Overflow, where validity or relevance can be influenced by technological evolution. Language *does* evolve, but not nearly as quickly as technology.

Answer (score 3):

### Unpinning makes sense for some questions and not others

Stack Exchange has three types of questions on the network:

1. Ones with an objective answer that is correct, and a different answer may become more correct over time
2. Ones with a combination of objective and subjective components to answers
3. Ones with *almost* entirely (but not completely) subjective components to answers

All three of these types are answerable on stack because all three types allow for expert opinion to avoid *wrong* answers. It is possible for there not to be a correct answer to a problem while simultaneously having very definite *wrong* answers. For example, "How would I solve world hunger in the world I am creating for my novel? (parameters are x)" would be a fine question for *[Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)*, it doesn't necessarily have one true "right" answer, it does, however have at least one very wrong answer "have [insert disaster] wipe out *everyone* on your world". Sure it solves the problem of world hunger, but leaves the querent without a world to build in. Expert opinion allows answers to avoid the wrong, and provide potential good solutions to the problem.

Whether or not a site should use the unpinning feature or not depends on what mix of these three types of questions there are on that site. Sites that have more of types 2 & 3 should retain pinning, sites that have more of type 1 should remove it.

### What does pinning actually achieve?

Pinning an answer gives the querent an active opinion on which answer solved their problem. Unpinning changes that opinion to being more passive (readers have to scroll past the first answer to get to an unpinned accepted answer, which is the use case this change is attempting to solve).

This decision seems to be based on the assumption that the querent is the least expert person in the discussion. Making this assumption in all cases is a dangerous road to go down.

The experiment this change was based on, was run on the site which has a plethora of objectively answered questions (Stack Overflow). In that situation the querent will be the least expert person in the room.

Someone, on the other hand, asking "How should I handle situation x which is causing issues for reasons x & y" is not a situation where the querent is the least expert person in the discussion, it's a situation where they may be the most expert person on what constitutes the *best* answer.

The moment you bring a subjective topic into a question is the same moment the fundamental assumption that the SO experiment was investigating shifts dramatically. For example, the querent cannot possibly put down all of the history and nuance of the interpersonal relationships (because space), however they are uniquely qualified to spot what is the best answer for their situation once presented (in that situation).

### Example Site Classifications

For sites where there is an objective answer to a question (*[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *Stack Overflow*, etc.), the querent's opinion doesn't matter as much on what is the best answer, as the best answer for the site is "what is the highest quality and most correct answer", which is a criteria that can change over time.

For sites where instead there is frequently going to be a subjective answer (*[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, etc.). Answers to these types of questions will (commonly) have two components, objective facts (e.g. game rules) and subjective opinion (how those game rules should be interpreted and applied). The querent's opinion on what solved their problem *should* hold more weight for these questions as it is a prominent and visible signal of what solved the subjective part of their problem.

There is a third set of questions which are (almost) totally subjective, those dealing with interpersonal relations. Given the focus of some sites (like *Role-playing Games*), we allow a subset of those (e.g., managing unruly players in my game, or x player's behaviour is unfun). For these types of questions the *most correct* answer is the one which solved the querents question the best, and this can only be indicated by pinning their accepted answer.

### So which of the two approaches should we take?

Given the different mix of questions that sites can have, it should be an opt-in situation for a site to de-pin accepted answers, as opposed to an opt-out of the de-pinning. This would produce the least harm.

As a counter point, I think a *better* approach would be to try and classify most sites in the network based on the balance of these three buckets of questions on their site. Then provide an initial rollout of de-pinning to those sites with primarily questions of type 1, with an opt-out for these sites. It should then be opt-in for all other sites.

When a site is in beta, it should be a configurable criteria by the mods of that site, so they can experiment and figure out which approach works best for their fledgling site. The final decision should then be made once the site graduates out of beta.

Comment: Some sites don't fit into these categories - for example, Puzzling has many questions with objectively correct answers which will never become outdated. But then Puzzling bucks the Q&A model in a lot of other ways as well.

Comment: @bobble I would put puzzling as containing type 1 questions. The "may become outdated" isn't a mandate that they will, just a possibility. For puzzling that possibility is 0 (without breaking logic). For something like physics.SE the possibility is also close to 0 (for example it's exceptionally unlikely that an answer about relativity would become outdated based on our current understanding). Puzzling, however, does have other features which make it particularly unique, and thus potentially unsuitable to lose the pinning behaviour even though it's primarily populated by type 1 questions.

Comment: For example, being *first* with an answer to a puzzle is an important criteria on puzzling.SE which the pinning behaviour rewards.

Comment: There are quirks - for example, riddles would ideally have an objectively correct answer but sometimes the factor determining checkmarking is just whichever answer was intended if multiple are plausible. (We have a close reason for that, if too many answers are plausible). But even then, which answer is considered correct by the poster is important information for evaluating the puzzle and the other answers, so pinning is beneficial.

Comment: "This decision seems to be based on the assumption that the querent is the least expert person in the discussion. Making this assumption in all cases is a dangerous road to go down." <-- my jaw dropped when I read this. It perfectly sums up the problem with automatically unpinning accepted answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'll repeat something I suggested on the math meta post:

A soft option  would be to make the tick ✅ count for some K≥1
upvotes, say
K=5
. Then early on, the accepted answer will be up top, but if a newer answer can prove itself, it will beat the accepted answer.

I would have liked to spend more time researching its effects eg with SEDE but I had other commitments. Its similar to [William Walker III's suggestion from politics.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369636/288791) to use a percentage modifier e.g. 125%, but it might be better suited for depreciating old answers (especially on popular posts) while still effectively pinning accepted answers before there are many votes.

Two basic examples comparing the two: if all answers have ≤3 votes, then 125% acts the same as a tie breaker. If the accepted answer has 100 votes, then 125% acts like my suggestion with the rather large K=25.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **unpinning** accepted answers, but **with a certain UI/UX change**.

There should be a checkmark under the question saying "this question has an accepted answer" that on hover/touch transiently shows overlay with accepted answer. This gets us best of both worlds - **current best answer on top** and **quick access to the answer that solved the question upon request (simply by hovering)**.

Comment: There is a similar "feature-request" that already suggests something like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369839/149167 ("Overlays" don't necessarily translate so well to mobile.)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a diverse number of answers ranging from all-in to all-out. So, here's another one to throw in the mix that aims at something already covered by the scope of each site:

> pseudo-[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
>
> Allow moderators the power to pin a specific answer above the accepted answer.

The motivation here is that the scope of per-site metas are specifically to discuss site-specific content. This includes questions about tagging, re-opening questions, why questions were closed, *etc.* Why not make questions about pinning a new (more appropriate) answer above the accepted answer part of that discussion. That is, someone would post a question, suggesting answer X should be pinned above the accepted answer Y and state the reasoning/motivation. The community can vote on it and a moderator takes action/not depending on result.

The accepted answer tick mark still represents "the answer that helped the OP most" (this was the original definition of the accept tick, if I recall). Not necessarily THE answer, but just the one they ended up using. A community discussion can opt for something more representative for the community to be ranked first, if that's the case.

Perhaps some sites can do with an all-in (top-voted answer is ranked *first*) approach, so this idea suggests a middle-ground that let the sites decide how they'd like to handle content on a per-question basis as and when needed.

The potential exists (although it's not necessary) for some larger reputation milestone for users who could achieve this new pinning privilege.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently we are planning to move forward with one of two scenarios,
> based on your feedback:
>
> 1. Unpin the accepted answer on all SE sites by default and pin it back
>    on a few sites that ask us to do so.
> 2. Keep the accepted answer pinned
>    on all SE sites by default and unpin it on a few sites that ask us to
>    do so.

I think the change should be applied network-wide.

This point formed part of [the answer by ColleenV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369577#369577), but I think it's a key point that merits its own consideration independently of the UI suggestion about a button.

As well as being "better than forcing each site to come to a consensus about whether to pin or not to pin" (per ColleenV), it is a more consistent overall UX for the network as a whole (who uses just one site?). Admittedly, sites already have subtle UI variations, but I feel this one would be a step too far.

Answer (score -2):

One thing people keep bringing up here, is that the asker of the question may not be the best qualified to judge which answer is the best. Could we make it so that the asker can earn the privilege to pin an answer to their own question, if they reach a high enough reputation, or earn for example, a gold (or platinum?) badge on one or more of the ***tags*** on the question? [Since at least six years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252690/391772), many users have expressed support for adding more reputation levels anyway :)

Comment: Reputation is not a measure of expertise in any topic other than “how to participate on the Stack Exchange network in a way that earns more reputation than it loses”.

Comment: @ColleenV yet reputation is what is needed to earn the privilege to upvote, to downvote, to edit, and to do many other things.

Comment: Making pinning a privilege does not solve the problem of askers being unqualified to judge which answer is best. Expressing "This is the answer that was most helpful to me personally." is not a privilege that needs to be earned. Having to earn the right to control how an accepted answer is displayed doesn't seem to fix anything. There will still be users pinning answers that the community thinks are wrong. There will still be answers that were fine when they were pinned, but are now obsolete.

Comment: **For 13 years SE has allowed the asker to pin their preferred answer to the top. I'm proposing a less drastic change.**

Comment: So, just to get this out of the way, I didn't downvote. I'm pointing out that I don't understand how this would be "better" instead of just "different". If you made that a little clearer, maybe I would be able to upvote it. I'm sorry if my comment came across as picking on your idea - that was not my intention.

Comment: @ColleenV This answer had a positive score of +1 before your comment. Often a negative comment can be 10x worse than a downvote. My understanding is that you feel that high-rep users may not know enough about a site's topic to deserve this privilege. Could you give an example of a high-rep user that is not very competent in a site's topic?

Comment: Or maybe more than one person is having a negative reaction to your idea for the same reasons I articulated. Would you rather have downvotes with no comments explaining why?  The topics a site covers are very broad. Show me a high reputation user on SO who is an expert in all of the top 50 tags. Also, remember you're talking about the person **asking** the question, who probably wouldn't be asking if they already knew everything about it. Reputation is not a measure of expertise. It's a measure of participation on the network and whether you can be trusted with various privileges.

Comment: You *do* realize that people have accepted wrong (as in malfunctioning) answers, as well as answers that contain known vulnerabilities or explicit Easter eggs to indicate that they were copied from Stack Overflow, right?  Allowing the OP to rank any answer gives the impression that they are an authority on what Right™ is, which leads to situations where people just copy bad code only because they blindly trust Stack Overflow.  So uh, no, the asker should get the ability to indicate that this answer worked for them, but if it really *is* bad, then the community gets to say that it is.

Comment: **StackOverflow is not the only site in this network.** Furthermore: for 13 years, OP has been allowed to pin their preferred answer to the top. Please stop pretending that this was a crazy, non-sensical idea.

Comment: This.   As an example https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/is-it-safe-to-cut-off-from-the-inside-of-my-helmet  the accepted answer is bad, unsafe, and flies in the face of common sense.  But OP accepted it so its at the top and will be first-answer to be read.   OP was looking for confirmation, rather than asking a serious question.

Comment: Excuse me, why are you writing that comment on my amswer? I'm suggesting that the user would need a lot of rep to pin answers to the top, and you've now shown an example of a user with 183 rep who you think made a bad decision on pinning an answer.

Comment: I can only go by my personal experience, which is that the best answers are most frequently the highest upvoted ones.

Comment: @ColleenV https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica If you're implying that getting a better than 15 score on an answer in a tag is a measure of expertise, I would disagree. Even if we forget for a moment that tagging is woefully inaccurate, a 15 score just means the person who is obviously the less informed of the pair liked the answer, not that it was correct or particularly erudite. That's just one of several reasons I can think of that makes generalist completely irrelevant to my point.

Comment: Colleen, you have replied in a similar way to 100% of the comments that disagree with your opinion. I don't think further [bludgeoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_bludgeon_the_process) will help.

Comment: The comment was addressed to me so I responded to it. If they didn't want a response, they shouldn't have pinged me. And yeah I noticed that you didn't.

Answer (score -11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It would be amazing if the OP could choose to pin the accepted answer or not! It would be better if there are choices.

Maybe, you could add a new privilege - *Vote for pinning accepted answers* for the high-reputation users and asker.

Or, you could just limit this privilege to the question-asker and the moderators

Comment: I think it's an interesting idea, but I don't think it solves the issues that pinning an accepted answer causes. This feature would make it seem like the issues could be solved if the community just tried harder, when the entire idea of pinning a single answer is kind of broken no matter how it's done.

Answer (score -17):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

TL;DR: change the design of accepted answers so that it's more obvious an answer is accepted, now that it's not pinned. My idea is have a background color for it. Mockup:

[image: mockup of background for accepted answer]

---

Reasoning:

The unpinning pretty much renders the accepted answer mechanism as whole almost pointless.

People knew that an answer was the "best" (in terms of helping the original question author) when it was on top. It was simple. Now people will just see a weird green "V" icon to the left of an answer and might just wonder what it means.

It's not bad; it's just a bigger change than what most people think, i.e. not just moving cheese, but turning the cheese into something else.

So to "compensate" over this, at least make it more obvious an answer is accepted, so that it will not be totally lost.

Comment: I'd instead want the preference idea in another answer. Should that be implemented, this would be moot.

Comment: @Sonic two different things. I don't talk about people who want to see it first, just a way to make it more clear "this answer is accepted, even though it is not on top".

Comment: If someone's disabled such a preference, I'm certain they wouldn't appreciate the answer being highlighted.

Comment: I disagree with this. The whole point of ending the accepted answer pinning is to lower the "authority" that the check yields, to highlight it less. I think that, a lot of the time, the accepted answer *shouldn't matter* to most folks (though, to be fair, I'm speaking largely about SO here), and the new change reflects this. The way I see it, adding more highlighting to accepted answers would counteract what this change aims to achieve.

Comment: @Sonic maybe people would like it, maybe not, we can't know. I'd like it, and keep in mind there are already background color used in several places: deleted posts, questions in lists which match favorite tags, etc. So the idea of background color for special occasions isn't new.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd posit that this would be an easy userscript to implement.

Comment: @zcoop98 there's no way I'm installing a userscript on my workplace PC. Give me vanilla.

Comment: The point of unpinning is to remove the special emphasis on that answer. The checkmark is staying, we don't need another indicator.

Comment: *"The unpinning pretty much renders the accepted answer mechanism as whole almost pointless"* - emphasis on almost. The way I see it, you get 15 extra rep for actually solving the OP's original problem. That's it! From there it's up to the community to decide the order of the answers by votes. The questions and answers should serve a greater purpose than to the one asked the question, but you still get a little "bonus" for actually helping them