# Accepting an answer still pushes it towards the top of the list of answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer, sorting, answer-order

It has been brought to my attention that, on sites where the [Would you like to have the accepted answer unpinned on your site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/773001) got applied, accepting an answer *does* push the answer towards the top of the list of answers. Consider this scenario:

- The accepted answer has a score of 1
- Another answer has a score of 1
- The rest of the answers have a score of 0

Currently, in the above case, the accepted answer **would be pinned to the top**, even though **another answer has the same score**. What does this mean in terms of calculating which post gets displayed above the others *(when sorting by score)*?

Does the checkmark count towards one vote, or half? Because if it's one, then it would mean that if the accepted answer has a score of 0, it would still be randomly ordered with the ones with a score of 1.

Finally, where is the fact *(that the checkmark counts towards which answer displays above the other answers)* mentioned in the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/773001)? It basically quotes

> By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

Which isn't really true. However, I am confused as to whether this is a recent change to the sorting of the answers, or was it always like this ever since the announcement.

Comment: Here is the feature request which has been implemented which requested that accepted answers rank above other answers with the same vote score: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569/299995

Comment: @bobble Not quite. I edited the post. There's also *"Does the checkmark count towards one vote, or half?"*

Comment: @AnnSaysDon'tGiveUp the basis of the dupe vote is the answer Cave linked which is [status-completed]

Comment: @bobble But given that it's an answer, I think it would be more appropriate to post an answer here pointing it out rather than closing this as a duplicate of the post. A user with the same question might have a hard time finding the link between this post and the dup target *(logical link, not hyperlink)*. *(P.S. sorry about all the edits.)*

Comment: @Ann If there's a comment pointing to an answer which directly addresses the question, I think that's a fine basis to dupe-vote and should be understandable to anyone who simply looks at the top comment. That way we have a signpost which points to where an answer may be found, and all the information is contained in one place.