# On sites where accepting an answer does not pin it, should it get a boost in rankings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, voting, accepted-answer

Some sites no longer pin accepted answers to the top. While I understand the reasoning (e.g. the OP's favorite answer might be wrong), it does seem like acceptance should "boost" the answer to some degree (especially on sites where an answer either works or doesn't work; the argument for this is weaker on sites like Politics where the OP might accept the answer they like, i.e. agree with, rather than a more accurate one). Perhaps at least on some sites, acceptance could either count as a fixed number of upvotes, or as a fraction of them (e.g. X% of the answer's regular upvotes)? A negative-scored accepted answer should probably not be boosted, though.

Comment: You know, [they said it would](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?page=1&tab=scoredesc#comment1240914_369569) but [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12119/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel even if that had been implemented, a 10-vote accepted answer (10A) would be below an 11-vote unaccepted answer (11U). I'm suggesting that a 10-vote accepted answer should be above an 11U, but probably below 20U. -1A would definitely be below 11U.

Comment: @Laurel the example you gave is a _self-accepted_ answer. Those were (and are) never given any priority even on sites where accepted answers are pinned. Non-self-accepted answers should (and do in my experience) count as a tie-breaker for posts of the same score.

Comment: @Laurel To try and validate Henry's point, I wrote an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1647947/questions-whose-accepted-answer-has-the-same-score-as-another-answer) to find questions with the accepted answer having the same score as another answer, refreshed the pages a few times, and it seems to always be given a priority (except when sorting by dates).

Comment: In what way does this help with anything? I don't see the reasoning  *why* should answers be boosted, so the question *should* they is a bit meaningless without such information.